# To split or not to split apk for upload in Playstore

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, google-play

If by splitting the apk, I reduce the size of the apk drastically, is it a bad idea to split the apk? In my case, for instance, I've lot of images in the app, each configured for varied device densities.

If it helps the end-user in the amount of storage-space and download-time for app-install, what stops everyone to configure split in gradle.

Google cautions on the multiple-apks approach as an advanced approach with lot of caveats in its [documentation](https://developer.android.com/google/play/publishing/multiple-apks.html). The problem is this doesn't help me decide on the situations that warrants multiple-apks.

I don't see any references on the pros and cons of this approach. Please advise based on your experience.

Comment: from what i remember from android guide rules (no time to search again now), you fall into the not many cases they recommend it (when you have lots of resources that are different depending on the target)

Comment: @Kaddath, thanks, I read those doc portions but couldn't make-up my mind on the pros/cons of the multiple-apks approach. I updated the question to reflect this dilemma of mine. I really want to see what has been the experience of those that tried that approach successfully and otherwise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can now use Android App Bundle to split apk and Google Play Store will handle the rest for you.

Note: You need Android Studio 3.2. or above version

Refer [Android Doc](https://developer.android.com/guide/app-bundle/) for more.

Answer (score 3):

Splitting the apk has its pros and cons, but it depends more of the market target for your app.

See emerging markets like Brazil for example where the average user has a weak device (like low storage) and even weaker cell infrastructure (low signal and or low data plan). For markets like this, if you want them to download your app, this app should be small, so it takes less space and consumes a low amount of their data plan. Here splitting the apk is likely the better option if your apk is something like 10Mb++ and the result of the splitting is a fraction of that. On other markets where the norm is bigger and better phones and a bigger data plan probably downloading a 40Mb apk is not an issue

But splitting is not a silver bullet, it may bring you problems. On a normal apk if a resource for a density is missing the system automatically uses the same resource for a different density, on a split apk this is not possible, the resource is missing and this should lead to an app crash.

Splitting should be based on the intended target market, some apps that target richer markets don't need to worry about splitting or not